# jQuery: do not add more clicks

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-effects

I hope to explain myself properly.
We have something like this (a simple example):

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    $('#a').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1500);
    $('#b').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1500);
    $('#b').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1500);
});
```

Now, if I click several times on "#click", even before the effects are finished, my repeated clicks are added together and the function executed multiple times (it's a really unpleasant thing especially when using "hover", as you know).

But I would like that clicks are detected only if effects are finished. How can I do?

I read the documentation about [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), but I'm not sure that will work in this case.
Can I have some examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with `queue`, just check the length of the queue, e.g.:

```
var a = $("#a");
if (a.queue().length === 0) {
    a.animate(...);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/aTeRIka/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/aTeRIka/1/edit)

You can create a tiny plug-in for this, if you like:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.maybeAnimate = maybeAnimate;
    function maybeAnimate() {
        var args = arguments;
        this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.queue().length === 0) {
                $this.animate.apply($this, args);
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

...and then use it like this:

```
$("#a").maybeAnimate({width: 'toggle'}, 1500);
$("#b").maybeAnimate({width: 'toggle'}, 1500);
$("#b").maybeAnimate({width: 'toggle'}, 1500); // Really #b again???
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/aTeRIka/4) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/aTeRIka/4/edit)

---

Re your comment below:

> But what to do when the function of the click is more complex and includes not only "animated", but different functions and also if/else? I wish that all the function of the click is a queue. Is it possible?

For combining the results of animations with other asynchronous things, you'd probably want to use [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [`Promise`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) objects. You can get the `Promise` for an animation from the jQuery set using [`.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/); e.g.:

```
 var p = $("#a").animate(/*...*/).promise();
```

You can then combine that promise with other promises/deferreds via [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when) and [`Promise#then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).

Comment: Ok @tjcrowder, this example works and it's the best solution to the problem. But what to do when the function of the click is more complex and includes not only "animated", but different functions and also if/else?  
I wish that all the function of the click is a queue. Is it possible?
Thank you.

Comment: @MirkoPagliai: I've copied your comment into the answer and added to the answer to point in a direction you might go. Re the fiddle: I'm not seeing any reason to use `.queue(letsAnimate)` then `.dequeue` when you know the queue is empty, rather than just calling `letsAnimate`.

Comment: @MirkoPagliai: For example, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/QyWn4/8/) that fiddle using promises to prevent the click from starting a new animation while the previous one is running. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/QyWn4/13/) one that allows you to schedule a new run while the previous one is running, just continually queuing them up.

Comment: Thanks @TJCrowder, you are very kind and your explanations are really clear and useful.  
Now I know how to do exactly what I want!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var isAnimating = $("#a").is(':animated');
```

Above code will return true, when element is animating.

Comment: Requires much more work for jQuery (parsing and dispatching the selector, which basically evaluates to checking the queue's length). Of course, clicks are human-generated events, so it's not like it matters.

Comment: Thank you.
This could work. Unfortunately it's not suitable when animations are so many and they have different times and/or different objects.
The example I quote is only explanatory, I seek a way to actually verify that no animation is still in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. Check out the documentation, it is the best solution to reset animations. I personally believe that every user input should be handled and never ignored. So I would stop the animation and start the new one.